# What is f(g(x)) ang g(f(x))

Tags: proof-verification, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f: \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ via $f(n, m) = n-m$
 and let $g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}$ via $g(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$

$g \circ f$ is defined since $g \circ f : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

$$\implies g(f(n,m)) = g(n-m) = \sqrt{n-m}$$

I don't get why $ f \circ g$ is not defined?

Comment: Does the output of $g$ look like an input for $f$?

Comment: Say $f$ takes integers and assign them to carrots. $g$ takes carrots and assign them to individuals. Then you can go from integers to individuals, but not from individuals to integers...

Comment: For $f(g(x))$ to be defined, you need $g(x)$ in the domain of $f$, which is not the case because $g(x)\in\mathbb{R}$ while the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}^2$.

Comment: @so basically in order for $f(g(x))$ to be defined g must have its codomain same as f's domain and for $(g(f(x))$ to be defined  f should have its codomain same as g's domain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The codomain of $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$, while the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{N}^2$, thus $g$ doesn't output the kinds of things that $f$ requires as input.  Hence the composition is not defined.

Edited to Elaborate:  When we say that $f : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$, we are declaring that $f$ is a function that eats pairs of natural numbers, and spits out integers.  If we try to feed $f$ with something that is not a pair of natural numbers, then $f$ chokes.

Next, note that $g : \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{R}$.  This means that $g$ eats integers, and spits out real numbers.  When we compose $g$ with $f$, i.e. when we try to define $g\circ f$, there is no problem.  $f$ outputs integers, and $g$ eats them up.  Groovy.

On the other hand, when we try to compose in the other way, i.e. to define $f\circ g$, $g$ outputs real numbers, and $f$, which is expecting pairs of natural numbers, chokes.  It can't handle what $g$ spits out, so the composition is nonsense.

Comment: just curious what codomain of g would make $f \circ g$ defined

Comment: We can only define the composition of functions if the first function maps its domain into the domain of the second function.  Since $f$ has $\mathbb{N}^2$ as its domain, $g$ would need to have $\mathbb{N}^2$ as its codomain in order for the composition $f\circ g$ to be defined.

Answer (score 1):

The functions can be composed one way as there is no break in the chain $\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ 
However $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^2$ requires a mapping that the functions can't perform.

More specifically as the integers are only a subset of the real numbers then it is possible that you wish to input a real number when only integers are permitted.  This wouldn't be so much of a problem the other way around.